# SQL Where clause using in array not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Where clause that is needed to properly filter my report. It's not working. 000 works but WAR does not. Please take a look and let me know if you have any suggestions.

```
    AND ((@Wharehouse ='000' AND wd.Whse  in('000','REP') AND wh.ParentWhse <> 'STR') 
     OR (@Wharehouse = 'WAR' AND wd.Whse in ('001','008','RMA') )
     OR (@Wharehouse <> '000' AND wd.Whse = @Wharehouse))
```

Edit:
We have several warehouses (ya, I misspelled the parameter) in our facility. For the report, when '000' is passed in, the resulting report will contain data from both the '000' and 'REP' warehouses. When 'WAR' is passed in, warehouses '001','008' and 'RMA' will be included in the results.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work`? Sample data, actual results, and desired results would be very helpful.

Comment: SQL Server 10
Doesn't work means I get zero data rows when WAR is submitted when data is actually available.

Comment: '000' has different conditions than 'WAR', so we need more info to determine what is wrong

Comment: Obviously when @Wharehouse is 'WAR', there are no records that have wd.Whse equal to '001','008' or 'RMA'.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: @Nick Abbot, could you explain your comment please?

Comment: @RickSavoy this is the criteria: (@Wharehouse = 'WAR' AND wd.Whse in ('001','008','RMA')) If you're not getting any rows for 'WAR' then Whse is not 001, 008 or RMA.

Comment: @Nick Abbot, I see, however, when I pass '001' as a parameter I do get results. It looks to me that only the last condition of the 3 is being executed and 'WAR' is not really a warehouse, just a group of warehouses. There are 4 options presented to the user. '000', 'WAR', 'POS' and 'STR'. of those only 'WAR' is not a warehouse itself.

Comment: we need the entire select statement

Comment: Ok, kick myself i the butt time. The code presented here is fine. My mistake was in a couple of temp tables I created to be used by this query. The didn't have the above code and when 'WAR' was passed in, their results were null.